# Find the sum of digits of m?

Tags: number-theory

> Let $m$ be the number of numbers from set $\{1,2,3,\dots,2014\}$ which can be expressed as difference of the squares of two non negative integers. The sum of digits of $m$ is...

My attempt: I tried one by one that $1,2,4,5,6,7$ and so on. But it was very long and still I didn't got the right answer. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $x^2 - y^2 = (x+y)(x-y)$.  $x+y$ and $x-y$ can be any integers that are either both odd or both even. So the only positive integers that **can't** be written in this way are ...

Comment: You mean to say that I should try this method for 1 to 2014.

Comment: check for 1 then 2 then 3 and so on

Comment: suppose I use this method and try for 64 then only possible values x-y and x+y would be factor of 64 then it would be 1×64,2×32,4×16,8×8,16×4,32×2,64×1.

Comment: for 64 only I will have to check 7 times and there are 2014 numbers to check.

Comment: What then: $64=16*4=(10+6)(10-6)=10^2-6^2$. But $x-y$ might be $1$ so I'm a little unsure what Robert is hinting at.

Comment: @Henrik this you have tried for only 64 and you are unsure we have to check 2014 numbers

Comment: You don't have to try all the possibilities, this gives a proof that a lot of numbers (as far as I can see more than Robert hinted at) can be expressed as the difference of two squares. As you don't need to know the squares that reduces your problem quite alot.

Comment: This is not a matter of checking.  It is finding the condition for a number $z$ to be expressible in this way in terms of the congruence class of $z \mod 4$.